# iOS: Automatically reestablishing Bluetooth BLE connection when in range

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is is possible to "pair" a Bluetooth BLE device such that they automatically connect when in range? (ie. an iPhone app sets up a connection to the Bluetooth device and from then on, the iPhone automatically reconnects to the device if in range, even if the app hasn't been opened in days and is fully closed).

Once reconnected, the device could either using Event Backgrounding to prompt the user to open the app or otherwise interact with a possibly backgrounded app (as described [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2011/Dec/msg00007.html)).

Anecdotally, I've used Bluetooth keyboards that automatically reconnect to my laptop when back in range. These are not necessarily BLE devices, is this something that's possible in BLE land?

Could this be possible if the iPhone were the server instead of the device? What if this were done using traditional Bluetooth under the MFI program?

There are number of relevant comments here and on the Apple [Bluetooth-dev mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/bluetooth-dev), but nothing that cleared it up for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted my question on Bluetooth-dev, I'm leaving the response here for posteriority:  http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2012/Sep/msg00117.html